# Preparation of KHSO4

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium

This is theoretical scheme for preparing $\ce{KHSO4}$:
$$\ce{K2CO3 + 2H2SO4 -> 2KHSO4 + CO2 +H2O}$$ 
using 1 eq $\ce{K2CO3}$ and 2 eq of $\ce{H2SO4}$ in approx 10 eq of $\ce{H2O}$ one gets $\ce{K2SO4}$ instead. How is it possible that $\ce{H2SO4}$ completely dissociated despite $\ce{HSO4-}$ is very weak acid in water? Does $\ce{K+}$ ion somehow influence the acidity of that anion? You have to use double the amount of sulfuric acid (4 eq) to get desired product. 
Also when using 1 eq $\ce{K2CO3}$ and **1 eq** of $\ce{H2SO4}$ what product would you expect? Mixture of $\ce{KHCO3}$ and $\ce{KHSO4}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pKa2 of sulfuric acid is 1.99 ([Table of pka](http://2012books.lardbucket.org/books/principles-of-general-chemistry-v1.0/s31-appendix-c-dissociation-consta.html)).  This is definitely less acidic than pKa1, but calling this a 'weak' acid may be a distraction.

The relevant question is: does $\ce{KHCO3}$ readily deprotonate $\ce{KHSO4}$?  The pKa1 of carbonic acid is 6.35 (same source), making it a weaker acid than  $\ce{KHSO4}$.  The difference is more than 4 orders of magnitude, so yes, I expect that $\ce{KHSO4}$ will more strongly favor depronotation than carbonic acid, and hence $\ce{K2SO4}$ is the product I expect.

To get at this quantitatively, consider the sub reaction:

$$\ce{KHCO3 + KHSO4 <=> K2SO4 + H2CO3 }$$

Which leads to the expression: 
$$\ce{K_{eq} = \frac{[K2SO4][H2CO3]}{[KHCO3][KHSO4]} }$$ 
which can be rewritten as
$$\ce{K_{eq} = \frac{[H^+][K2SO4][H2CO3]}{[H^+][KHCO3][KHSO4]} }$$ 
Which can be rewritten as 
$$\ce{K_{eq} = \frac{[H2CO3]}{[H^+][KHCO3]}\cdot\frac{[H^+][K2SO4]}{[KHSO4]}}$$ 
which can be written as 
$$\ce{K_{eq} = \frac{$K$_{a2,\ce{KHSO4}}}{$K$_{a1,\ce{H2CO3}}} }$$ 
Taking the log of both sides 
$$\ce{pK_{eq} = p$K$_{a2,\ce{KHSO4}} - p$K$_{a1,\ce{H2CO3}} = } -4.36$$

Which is $$\ce{K_{eq} \approx 23,000}$$ heavily favoring products, and hence, $\ce{K2SO4}$ is the dominant product